# Cucumber Scenario Parallelization instead of by .feature?

Tags: parallel-processing, cucumber, scenarios

In order to maximize the parallelization of tests runs, I've separated out all tests to have their own feature file and I run the Parallel_Cucumber Gem with great success but while my tests are relatively speedy, I find repeating myself a lot...

So I was wondering if there is a way to consolidate repeating tests into **scenario** outlines while still keeping the same amount of parallelization I have now.

So basically a way to read the .feature scenarios and spin those scenarios on its on browser instance.

Any help / guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We were in a similar situation and we are using cucumber-JVM and I have come up with a Gradle plugin which will read a feature file matching tags, and generate a feature file per scenario with an associated junit test runner.

These junit test runners will then be executed in parallel by Gradle's test task based the number of forks option. You can take a look at [this implementation](https://github.com/puttagunta/supercucumber) for an idea.